# Cannot find elements within a div tag - Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

```
<div id="template_data">
<input id="reservaActual" type="hidden">
<input id="_ctl0_data_holder_idResActual" name="_ctl0:data_holder:idResActual" type="hidden">
<table id="MainScreen" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td id="panizq" class="PanelIzq" valign="top">
```

Within the above html, I am able to find the `template_data` which is a div tag but  Iam unable to find anything within, not the input `id="_ctl0_data_holder_idResActual"`, nor the table id `MainScreen` or the td id `panizq`.

I've tried xpath, cssselectors, ids but not luck. I want to start from scrath and have ideas on what I can try because I am not sure if i need to go through levels but want to see how people on SO try to tackle this issue and go through it with somebody:

Below is my code;

```
        public void SelectAgency()
            {
    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
               _driver.FindElement(By.Id("template_data"));
}
```

Comment: Which exception are you getting? Maybe you've found your element correctly but you want to interact with it and it's not interacting in the way you expect it to interact.

Comment: All exceptions have stated they could not find their relevant method and selectors for each one. When going into it deeper they all output null

Comment: That `div` might be located inside an `iframe`. Check this assumption and let me know

Comment: @Andersson It is deffo not in an iframe, me and my colleague are looking at it and it's baffling how it's not finding it. Can I ask if there are lots of javascript code, can it have an affect on when we're trying to find elements?

Comment: I faced a somewhat similar issue a few days ago. I was able to find the elements but when I tried interacting with it or to fetch it's elements, it either spit out null or gave me stale element reference exception. After digging deep, I found that the JavaScript code was refreshing all the dom elements after every 5 sec, hence they all were dead before I could interact with it. Try looking at JS code, maybe the DOM is being modified somehwere

Comment: We figured it out, virtually when this page is open, it's open in a new tab, the template_data is also found in the former page so we needed to call on the current tab we're in before making calls to find elements